# Combining CSV files within Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, landsat-8

I have a script in EE (below) which is mapping a function to calculate Land Surface Temperature in my area of interest across multiple years of Landsat 8 scenes (filtered for clear terrain using the BQA band) within two image collections - pre/post-construction of a solar power station.

When exporting CSV files - one for each scene - each file requires at least 2 clicks.  In my initial sample site my script finds about 300 scenes, so 600 clicks.

In addition, the loop to export the CSV files throws this error due to the high number of scenes:

```
Line 89: List.get: List index must be between 0 and 92, or -93 and -1.  Found 93.
```

Is it possible to combine the CSV files within EE prior to export?
What is the best way to resolve the List index error?

Code:

```
// Load GEE toolbox - https://github.com/sacridini/GEET
var geet = require('users/elacerda/geet:geet'); 

// Function to filter for 'Clear terrain' pixels using BQA band
function CloudRemoval (image) {
    var removeCloud = image.mask(image.select('BQA').eq(2720))
    return removeCloud
  }

// Select sample site
var site = "Stateline"; 

// Image COllections of Landsat 8 scenes
// Pre-construction image collection (up to month preceeding construction)
var pre_collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
                    .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-09-30')
                    .map(CloudRemoval)
                    .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[-115.50406614745035, 35.63322800145796],
            [-115.50406614745035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.63322800145796]]], null, false))

// Post-construction image collection (from month after site is commissioned to present)
var post_collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
                    .filterDate('2016-08-01', '2021-09-20')
                    .map(CloudRemoval)
                    .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[-115.50406614745035, 35.63322800145796],
            [-115.50406614745035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.63322800145796]]], null, false));

//Set unmasked buffers (generated using separate script)
var unmaskedBuffers = ee.FeatureCollection('users/.../utility_solar_lst/stateline/'+site+'_unmaskedBuffers');

/////Set masked buffers (generated using separate script and hand-drawn geometry to mask areas that might distort analysis)
var maskedBuffers = ee.FeatureCollection('users/.../utility_solar_lst/stateline/'+site+'_maskedBuffers');

//Merge buffers into single feature collection to allow mean LST to be calculated for both buffers simultaneously
var buffers = unmaskedBuffers.merge(maskedBuffers);

//Function to calculate LST image for Landsat 8
//Method taken from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298616/estimating-land-surface-temp-using-geet
var calculateLST_L8 = function(image){
    var new_toa_radiance = geet.toa_radiance(image, 10);
    // geet.brightness.temp_l8c calls the GEET function to convert to degrees celcius using doulbe band processing (B10 and B11) to determine BT.
    var brightness_temp_img = geet.brightness_temp_l8c(new_toa_radiance, true);
    var l8_ndvi = geet.ndvi_l8(brightness_temp_img); 
    var img_pv = geet.prop_veg(l8_ndvi);
    var lse = geet.surface_emissivity(img_pv);
    var surfTemp_img = geet.surface_temperature_oli(lse);
    //var im = surfTemp_img.select("LST");
    return surfTemp_img;
  };

//Map calculateLST (_L5/_L8) function over pre- & post-construction image collections to create LST images
// Changed pre_LSTcollection reference to L8
var pre_LSTcollection = pre_collection.map(calculateLST_L8);
var post_LSTcollection = post_collection.map(calculateLST_L8);


//Function to extract average LST in each buffer - both masked & unmasked buffers
var bufferLST = function(image){
    var LST = image.select('LST');
    var meanLST = LST.reduceRegions({
      collection: buffers,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 30
    });
    return meanLST;
  };

  /////Map bufferLST function over pre- and post-construction LST image collections
var pre_bufferLST = pre_LSTcollection.map(bufferLST);
var post_bufferLST = post_LSTcollection.map(bufferLST);

//Convert collections to list for use in export loop
var pre_bufferLST_list = pre_bufferLST.toList(pre_bufferLST.size());
var post_bufferLST_list = post_bufferLST.toList(post_bufferLST.size());

/////Loop to export pre-construction LST buffer data to drive
///Produces 1 CSV file for LST buffer data (masked & unmasked) for each pre-construction image date
for (var f = 0; f<1000; f++){
    ////Select feature collection and order by type (masked/unmasked)
      var feature = ee.FeatureCollection(pre_bufferLST_list.get(f));
      var feature = feature.sort('type');
    ////Get the date for the collection - used for export filename
      var date = feature.get('system:index').getInfo();
      var order = date.slice(5,7);
    ////Export table to drive - file/folder names update automatically
      Export.table.toDrive({
        collection: feature,
        description:order+site+'_preLST_'+date,
        folder: site,
        fileFormat:'CSV',
    ////Only export relevant columns
        selectors:['type','buffer','mean']
      });
    }

    /////Loop to export post-construction LST buffer data to drive
///Produces 1 CSV file for LST buffer data (masked & unmasked) for each post-construction image date 
for (var f = 0; f<1000; f++){
    ////Select feature collection and order by type (masked/unmasked)
      var feature = ee.FeatureCollection(post_bufferLST_list.get(f));
      var feature = feature.sort('type');
    ////Get the date for the collection - used for export filename
      var date = feature.get('system:index').getInfo();
      var order = date.slice(5,7);
    ////Export table to drive - file/folder names update automatically
      Export.table.toDrive({
        collection: feature,
        description:order+site+'_postLST_'+date,
        folder: site,
        fileFormat:'CSV',
    ////Only export relevant columns
       selectors:['type','buffer','mean']
      });
    }
```

Comment: There's a whole bunch of bad practices in here.  You shouldn't be using getInfo, converting to lists, using for loops or running a zillion small exports.   (See: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices and https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging).   Instead, merge your collections and export them as one (or two) big exports.  You can copy the system:index into each reduceRegions result (via a map) to help identify them.

Comment: Thanks, Noel.  Your points thankfully relate to inherited code.  Could I ask for a bit of clarification?  Your suggestion is to merge the two image collections and map the system:index to ID each.  Do I map the export process?  (I haven't re-read the docs you link to yet so please point me to them if appropriate).  Any further context is very helpful, though.

Comment: Sorry, but the docs don't help me much.  I don't know enough Javascript and don't have enough experience.  To merge the collections I'd do something like `var Collection = preLST_collection.merge(postLST_collection)`.  So now I have one large collection of processed LST images derived from the original Landsat 8 scenes.  If I did this with the pre_bufferLST and post_bufferLST collection I end up with LST data extracted for each of my buffers around the solar sites.  I'm not clear what format this data is, though, and how to export it using a mapped function as a one/two CSV files as suggested.

Comment: A further complication is that I need to introduce an additional mapped function to filter by the proportion of pixels that remain in the aoi after clouds have been masked.  If too much terrain is masked then the LST values become unreliable as variance increases signifiantly.