# Mapping system:index to ID data then exporting one/two large CSVs

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I asked a similar question recently and @Noel Gorelick provided some suggestions of how to proceed.

His advice was to:

- Merge your collections (I think I've done this below)
- "Export the merged collection(s) as one (or two) big exports. You can copy the system:index into each reduceRegions result (via a map) to help identify them".

The second point is where I am stuck.  I understand what .map does, but I don't know how to incorporate it correctly at either the 'reduceRegions' step, or in the Export code.

I've tried many many times but only seem to break my code in new and inexplicable ways.

The outcome I'm looking for is a single CSV with 20 LST data per month (one for each of 20 buffers) with each value associated with the capture time of the original Landsat 8 scene from which the lST values are calculated.

If I can get this to work I can get started with a ton of analysis in R.  I would happily bounty this if I could!

```
// Image Collections of Landsat 8 scenes
// Pre-construction image collection (up to month preceeding construction of solar park)

var pre_collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
                    .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-09-30')
                    .map(CloudRemoval)
                    .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[-115.50406614745035, 35.63322800145796],
            [-115.50406614745035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.63322800145796]]], null, false))

// Post-construction image collection (from month after site is commissioned to present)

var post_collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
                    .filterDate('2016-08-01', '2021-10-20')
                    .map(CloudRemoval)
                    .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[-115.50406614745035, 35.63322800145796],
            [-115.50406614745035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.53215170563853],
            [-115.37223020995035, 35.63322800145796]]], null, false));

/////Set masked buffers (generated using separate script and hand-drawn geometry to mask areas that might distort analysis)

var maskedBuffers = ee.FeatureCollection('users/.../utility_solar_lst/stateline/'+site+'_maskedBuffers');

//Merge buffers into single feature collection to allow mean LST to be calculated for both buffers simultaneously

var buffers = unmaskedBuffers.merge(maskedBuffers);

//Function to calculate LST image for Landsat 8
//Method taken from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298616/estimating-land-surface-temp-using-geet
var calculateLST_L8 
<snip!>

// Join the ImageCollections
var Collection = preLST_collection.merge(postLST_collection)

// Map calculateLST function over merged ImageCollection to create LST images

var LSTcollection = Collection.map(calculateLST_L8);

//Function to extract average LST in each buffer and add system_index value

var bufferLST = function(image){
    var LST = image.select('LST');
    var meanLST = LST.reduceRegions({
      collection: buffers,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 30,
    });
    return meanLST;
  };

// Map bufferLST function over merged pre- and post-construction LST image collections

var bufferLST = LSTcollection.map(bufferLST);
var buffer_data =  ee.FeatureCollection(buffer_data);

Export.table.toDrive({
        collection: buffer_data,
        description: 'system:index',
        folder: site,
        fileFormat:'CSV',
    ////Only export relevant columns
        selectors:['type','buffer','mean']
      });
```

[Code editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fprmonk%2FLearning%3AStateline_all_scenes).

Comment: I understand that you are stuck in a project that has some history as to how you came to this particular issue. We can help you with that. At the same time, it would be nice if a stack exchange post is as generic as possible to have the most encyclopedic value for other users. I suggest you edit your question and retain only the most important information necessary to explain your issue. Of course you can link to your other question to explain how you got here

Comment: I've done my best - hope that's better!

Comment: Code editor script link does not work. Can you fix it?

Comment: Sorry - I've been unwell (and away).  Does this work?  https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fprmonk%2FLearning%3AStateline_all_scenes